# Why the first element in the chart does not show when the background svg path is behind it?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, visualization, pie-chart

I am working on a variable radius pie chart. The original code was from here: https://embed.plnkr.co/plunk/atGc2B. I have added a background of a doughnut shape which works fine. But when the background path is there, the first element in the chart does not show.

Here are images of what happens without and with the background.

[Desired view of chart without background](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iTt6j.png)

[Broken chart with background](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I87xX.png)

Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
     <meta charset="utf-8" />
     <title>D3.js Variable Radius Donut Chart</title>
     <link data-require="normalize@*" data-semver="3.0.1" rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/3.0.1/normalize.min.css" />

    <style>
        body {
          background-color: #282a35;
        }

        #bg svg {
          position: relative;
          z-index: 0; 
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="chart"></div>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.6/d3.min.js" data-semver="3.4.6" data-require="d3@*"></script>
  <script>
            (function(d3) {
                'use strict';

                var dataset = [
            //    { count: 0, size: 0, label: '', colour: '' },
                  { count: 3, size: 30, label: 'Use', colour: 'slateblue' }, 
                  { count: 1, size: 10, label: 'Production', colour: 'yellow' },
                  { count: 15, size: 100, label: 'Distribution', colour: 'orange' },
                ];

                var width = 500;
                var height = 500;
                var donutWidth = 50;
                var innerRadius = (Math.min(width, height) / 4.5) - donutWidth;
                
                var svg = d3.select('#chart')
                  .append('svg')
                  .attr('width', width)
                  .attr('height', height)
                  .style('position', 'relative')
                  .style('z-index', 1)
                  .append('g')
                  .attr('transform', 'translate(' + (width / 2) + 
                    ',' + (height / 2) + ')');
                
                var arc = d3.svg.arc()
                  .innerRadius(innerRadius)
                  .outerRadius(function (d) { 
                    return innerRadius + d.data.size; 
                  });
                

                var pie = d3.layout.pie()
                  .value(function(d) { return d.count; })
                  .sort(null);
                
                var data = pie(dataset);
                
                //I don't know why this background doughnut is not working.
                var bg = svg.append('path')
                  .attr('d', d3.svg.arc()
                    .innerRadius(innerRadius-10)
                    .outerRadius(innerRadius + donutWidth + 80)
                    .startAngle(0)
                    .endAngle(2 * Math.PI))
                  .attr('fill', '#18a34a');

                var path = svg.selectAll('path')
                  .data(data)
                  .enter()
                  .append('path')
                  .attr('d', arc)
                  .attr('fill', function(d){return d.data.colour});

                var text = svg.selectAll('text')
                  .data(data)
                  .enter()
                  .append('text')
                  .text(function(d) { 
                    return d.data.label + ": " + d.data.count; 
                  })
                  .attr('transform', function(d) {
                    var c = arc.centroid(d),
                      x = c[0],
                      y = c[1],
                      h = Math.sqrt(x*x + y*y);
                  return 'translate(' + (x/h * (innerRadius+donutWidth/2)) + ',' +
                     (y/h * (innerRadius+donutWidth/2)) +  ')';
                })
                  .attr('dy', '.35em')
                  .attr('fill', 'black')
                  .attr('text-anchor', function(d) {
            return (d.endAngle + d.startAngle)/2 > Math.PI ?
                'end' : 'start';
                  });
                
              })(window.d3);

    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally got it working, needed to add .slice to the path that draws the chart:

```
var path = svg.selectAll('path.slice')
                  .data(data)
                  .enter()
                  .append('path')
                  .attr('d', arc)
                  .attr('fill', function(d){return d.data.colour});
```